# Do performers arrive before or after the audience?

Tags: live-music, singers, performance

Is there a set rule for performers to arrive before or after the crowd? Or, is it up to each performer's choice?

**Note:** I am not asking about festivals, but just concerts.

Comment: No sources (hence not posted as an answer), but logic would suggest no rules because you don't piss off the talent with demands (suggestions per venue might be possible) and they arrive before. After all, they would travel on the same roadways as the crowd to get to the venue and their crew needs to set up before the show starts.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I do know that some artists (e.g. Harry Styles) enters the same time as the crowd so that he can greet them.

Comment: @taylor.2317 True, but in that example, he's probably already been at the venue for several hours prior to that.  Obviously high-grossing pop artists aren't huffing their own gear in and out, but there are still sound checks, rehearsals, blocking, PR, etc. that take place before the audience shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons for performers to turn up hours before a concert. They might even be there all day rehearsing. Mostly there's a sound check an hour or two before the concert. Often there is a make-up call.

On the other hand, I've seen performers turn up with literally a minute to spare.

And anything in between. If there are no other constraints probably most people would choose to be at the venue about 30-60 minutes before the concert.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the answer depends on what you mean by *arrive* and whether it is to appear on stage or in the same city/building.

Assuming, we talk about appearing on stage, I experienced the the following for classical music performances:

- chamber musicians appear on stage, just before the concert starts. It takes long enough for the concert hall to become quiet. (And the performers can tune elsewhere easily)
- orchestras may already be on stage (or for operas in the orchestra pit) and do the major amount of work related to tuning, since the instruments are there, some not easily transported, or at least not without harming the tuning. They may disappear to re-dress later before thee concert begins.